# timer interrupts on an esp8266

Tags: interrupt, timers

Folks.
I'm working on an ESP8266 and keen to switch to using:

- an object approach -> sorted;
- physical interrupts on the hardware pins -> sorted;
- timer interrupts -> driving me crazy!

My problems are that:

- There are so many timer libraries
- I can't find one that works on my set-up; either they don't compile, or they have unfulfilled dependencies
- Some look promising, but then it turns out something needs to be polled to see if the timer has triggered

Can anyone help me out here please?  I just want a straight-forward approach to setting a simple timer on the 8266 that will trigger an ISR where I can switch off an output now and then tidy up later.

Regards, David (Southampton)

Comment: Have you looked at the Ticker class (the one included in ESP8266 platform?)

Comment: Brilliant - it's simple yet flexible, it compiles - and it does the job.  Thank you!